# iOS App Update Version 1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I created an app in cocos2d v2 and I want to make my first update to my app. I want to add a physics engine this time so I need to use cocos2d v3. So how would I tell apple that this is my update for my app and not a new app entirely? I know you can just set the version # in XCode but the problem is that it is a completely different project since I am implementing v3 instead of v2. How do I do this?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but all you need to do is read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ShippingandUpdatingYourApp/ShippingandUpdatingYourApp.html)

Comment: You can actually hook up Box2D or Chipmunk to Cocos2d v2. I would recommend doing that, if your game is large. Cocos v3 is not retrocompatible so you have to rewrite a lot of your code if you choose to go down this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter to Apple if it's a new project. Apple only cares about the bundle ID. If the bundle ID is the same, and you sign with the same certificate, and the version number is higher than before, then you're good to go.

Apple would never restrict uploads to project files. Then, how could you rewrite your app, or continue development if you lose your source? That would be absurd. Check the app update guide by Apple if you need more info on what you *need* to update an app.

Comment: You do not need to sign it with the same certificate. It just has to be your certificate. Remember, you need to renew a new certificate once a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cocos2d, one option is just to replace the coco2d folder in your current project with the updated version (v3). This would give you all the new code and you wouldn't need to make a new project.

That said, the Bundle Identifier is what identifies the app (change it in the project settings). Just make sure that is the same, and the app will override the previous version.